# Xcode 8 AppStore upload (error 434)

Tags: validation, upload, app-store, xcode8

When I tried to validate an `App Store` build using `Xcode 8` I'm getting the following error:

```
ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain 434.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I don't know what it means but I know it did stop me from uploading immediately afterwards. Some people say it's intermittent so it might be yet another "Apple glitch".

Comment: Hi Rameez,I am also getting same error did you find any solution for that.

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu. Even  i am getting same error now.

Comment: @madhavi do you know what exactly error is

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu. I don't know .Y it is getting also i don't know.What is Xcode version of yours? & swift Version

Comment: @ madhavi my xcode version is 8.1 and I am using objective c.what about you.

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu . Mine too Xcode 8.1 & swift 2.3 i am using. Seems there is problem with apple server.

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu.It was resolved for me.By restarting xcode

Answer (score 11):

I received the same error on multiple attempts. I made some changes (to provisioning profiles etc.) and then validation worked fine a couple of times. But then the error message came back for no apparent reason. Seems like a bug on Apple's side.

Since then I switched to use Application Loader, and with that workflow I have not encountered any problems. Here's how.

1. In the Xcode Organizer, I do not use "Validate...", but instead "Export..." to save the my_product.ipa file.
2. Then open Apple's Application Loader (Xcode menu > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader), and with that I upload the my_product.ipa to iTunes Connect.

This process has seemed reliable to me.

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I found a different workflow which has resolved the issue for me. I just edited my answer to describe that workflow. Good luck!

Comment: Thank u but for me by just restarting Xcode it was resolved

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I'm glad it works for you again, but just beware, that my experience is that this problem would come and go. I would make some changes and suddenly it would work, then suddenly fail again. My experience is that the Application Loader is actually reliable.

Comment: I successessfully uploaded the .ipa file using the Application Loader. But I don't see it anywhere in the iTunes Connect. How do I find it?

Comment: @Isuru If I remember right, it will show up under the "Build" section, but it may take a while (hours?) before it has completed processing and actually shows up. So check again after a while.

Comment: @rene Yes, it showed up after a few minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I received the same error on multiple times. Change some codes, finally release that :

Solution:

```
unchecked "include bitcode" , then validate (in my case it was successful)
```

After

```
Validate with checked "include bitcode"
```

P.S : Next time, I used XCODE Application Loader. It will be ok for deploy your application.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this appears to be intermittent. I just received the error and literally did a retry without doing anything else and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen more reports of this, and some seemingly unrelated but very similar messages from other services. I finally submitted a Code-Level Support Technical Support Incident (TSI). After two days I was told this is not a "code" issue and was credited the TSI i burned when submitting the questions.  They got everything they needed to see the problem, but since they called me "John" in their answer, and they clearly saw my name was "Harry", hmm...

the reply, exactly:

> Blockquote
>   Please include the line below in follow-up emails for this request.
>   Follow-up: 651327438
>   Hello John,
>   Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). We provide support for code-level questions on hardware & software development, and are unable to help you with your question. For questions regarding iTunes Connect, we recommend that you first check the iTunes Connect Developer guide.
>   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iTunesConnectGuide
>   If you are not able to find the information you need in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide and you are still not able to resolve your issue, please direct your inquiry through the iTunes Connect Contact Us system When contacting the iTunes Connect Team, be sure to mention that you were referred by DTS.
>   Note that some issues with iTunes Connect are transient, and may resolved by waiting a few hours and trying again later.

Bottom Line: I gave up and uploaded the archive. It was accepted. I will update when the app is live.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode and re-login as suggested by members does not work for me. I solved it by using Application Loader.

Steps:

1. Change the version and build in your app.
2. Archive again for new file submission and export file to desktop.
3. Goto top menu: `Open Developer Tool > Application Loader` (if you don't have this, search, download and install this plug init)
4. Upload the new version archived file. Done

You will find them in iTunes Connect. From here process to My Apps > Choose the rejected app > Change the version and click on the new uploaded archive file, file will be processing.

5. Time to resubmit.