# Submit universal app within support portrait only

Tags: ios, iphone

I created an universal app and upload to appstore. But I got an error "ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 434" when I validate this build. My app supports portrait only. I'm not sure it is the reason I can not upload this app successfully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 AppStore upload (error 434)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140560/xcode-8-appstore-upload-error-434)

Answer (score 2):

That's because iPad apps should at least support 2 orientations. You could add `Upside Down` (which is just portrait orientation upside down) orientation, and it should get uploaded correctly. I'm not sure why you are receiving the mentioned error though.

Comment: Exactly...you can check with link which i post above

Comment: I set YES to UIRequiresFullScreen. It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

From [Technical Q&A QA1689](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1689/_index.html)

> Which orientations should my iPad application support?

You should always make your application support ***both variants*** of an orientation. More specifically, if your application supports portrait, then it should support both UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait and UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown; if your application supports landscape, then it should support both UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with your device orientation support.

check these answers,

[Strange Errors on Archive Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566481/strange-errors-on-archive-validation)

[Xcode 8 AppStore upload (error 434)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140560/xcode-8-appstore-upload-error-434)